# How to create a reading position indicator using Anime.js

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Im struggling to replicate this jQuery-based progress indicator script in Anime JS. This comes from a tutorial here: https://css-tricks.com/reading-position-indicator/

Is it possible to detect scroll position with just Anime or vanilla JS? Im trying to avoid adding jQuery as another library if possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Progress Indicator - JQuery</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <progress value="0"></progress>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      var winHeight = $(window).height(),
          docHeight = $(document).height(),
          progressBar = $('progress'),
          max, value;

      /* Set the max scrollable area */
      max = docHeight - winHeight;
      progressBar.attr('max', max);

      $(document).on('scroll', function(){
         value = $(window).scrollTop();
         progressBar.attr('value', value);
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```